# How to transfer special characters like äöü in the command line to emacsclient?

Tags: emacsclient, microsoft-windows, character-encoding

I try to create an interaction between `Emacs` and other applications, e. g. Microsoft Office.

For example I have defined a VBA Macro in `MS Outlook` which starts a search in Emacs:

```
strEmacsclientPath = "C:\emacs\emacs-24.3\bin\emacsclient.exe"

strShellCommand = strEmacsclientPath & " -c --eval " & Chr(34) & "(org-search-view nil" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) _
    & strSearchText _
    & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")" & Chr(34)

Call Shell(strShellCommand, vbHide)
```

This works, but if the text to search (defined in variable *strSearchText* ) contains special characters like **äöü**, it fails, as e. g. with the search term "für", in Emacs I get

```
Search words: f\374r
```

In consequence, it also does not find real occurrences of the search term "für".

How can I avoid that?

---

I've redefined the encoding settings, as I also had problems in the past:

```
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(setq coding-system-for-read 'utf-8)
(setq coding-system-for-write 'utf-8)
```

Here are the complete current encoding settings (obtained with `C-h C RET`)

> Coding system for saving this buffer:   U -- utf-8-dos (alias:
>   mule-utf-8-dos)
>
> Default coding system (for new files):   U -- utf-8 (alias:
>   mule-utf-8)
>
> Coding system for keyboard input:   1 -- iso-latin-1-unix (alias:
>   iso-8859-1-unix latin-1-unix)
>
> Coding system for terminal output:   * -- cp1252 (alias of
>   windows-1252)
>
> Coding system for inter-client cut and paste:   U -- utf-16le-dos
>
> Defaults for subprocess I/O:   decoding: U -- utf-8-unix (alias:
>   mule-utf-8-unix)
>
> encoding: U -- utf-8-unix (alias: mule-utf-8-unix)
>
> Priority order for recognizing coding systems when reading files:
>     1. utf-8 (alias: mule-utf-8)
>     2. iso-2022-7bit
>     3. iso-latin-1 (alias: iso-8859-1 latin-1)
>     4. iso-2022-7bit-lock (alias: iso-2022-int-1)
>     5. iso-2022-8bit-ss2
>     6. emacs-mule
>     7. raw-text
>     8. iso-2022-jp (alias: junet)
>     9. in-is13194-devanagari (alias: devanagari)
>     10. chinese-iso-8bit (alias: cn-gb-2312 euc-china euc-cn cn-gb gb2312)
>     11. utf-8-auto
>     12. utf-8-with-signature
>     13. utf-16
>     14. utf-16be-with-signature (alias: utf-16-be)
>     15. utf-16le-with-signature (alias: utf-16-le)
>     16. utf-16be
>     17. utf-16le
>     18. japanese-shift-jis (alias: shift_jis sjis)
>     19. chinese-big5 (alias: big5 cn-big5 cp950)
>     20. undecided
>
> Other coding systems cannot be distinguished automatically   from
>   these, and therefore cannot be recognized automatically   with the
>   present coding system priorities.
>
> Particular coding systems specified for certain file names:
>
> OPERATION   TARGET PATTERN      CODING SYSTEM(s)
>   --------- --------------      ----------------
>   File I/O   "\.dz\'"      (no-conversion . no-conversion) 
>         "\.xz\'"      (no-conversion . no-conversion)
>         "\.lzma\'"        (no-conversion . no-conversion)
>         "\.lz\'"      (no-conversion . no-conversion)
>         "\.g?z\'"     (no-conversion . no-conversion)
>         "\.\(?:tgz\|svgz\|sifz\)\'"
>                     (no-conversion . no-conversion)         "\.tbz2?\'"         (no-conversion . no-conversion)       "\.bz2\'"     (no-conversion . no-conversion)
>         "\.Z\'"       (no-conversion . no-conversion)
>         "\.elc\'"     utf-8-emacs         "\.utf\(-8\)?\'"    utf-8
>         "\.xml\'"     xml-find-file-coding-system
>         "\(\`\|/\)loaddefs.el\'"
>                     (raw-text . raw-text-unix)      "\.tar\'"     (no-conversion .   no-conversion)       "\.po[tx]?\'\|\.po\."
>                     po-find-file-coding-system      "\.\(tex\|ltx\|dtx\|drv\)\'"
>                     latexenc-find-file-coding-system        ""          find-buffer-file-type-coding-system   Process
>   I/O   "[pP][lL][iI][nN][kK]"  (undecided-dos . undecided-dos)
>         "[cC][mM][dD][pP][rR][oO][xX][yY]"
>                     (undecided-dos . undecided-dos)   Network I/O   nothing specified

Comment: This is a problem with file encoding I think. `\374` is an octal character. Emacs likes UTF-8 but Windows uses UTF-16. But by default on Windows Emacs should play nicely. What are your current encoding settings? Use `C-h C RET` to look at some of them.

Comment: My settings are a bit different. E.g., `iso-latin-1-dos` is my default. Are you modifying the settings in your `init.el`?

Comment: see my last edit.

Comment: Yeah, I think those lines might be your problem. Have you tried Stefan's suggestion? I also had problems and tried to force Emacs to use utf-8, but I ending up taking out all my coding settings and just using the defaults and it's worked okay since.

Comment: if I go back to the standard encoding in emacs, what'll happen to my existing text files? Will they get messed up?

Comment: second question: in which encoding do I have to convert my characters in VBA to get it correctly into emacsclient?

Comment: I'm really not sure, I'm sorry. That's why I didn't submit an answer. I just knew it was a coding issue.

Answer (score 1):

As @nanny says, this is a problem of character encoding.  I suggest you try something like (beware, I know nothing about VBA, so I'm just guessing at the syntax):

```
strShellCommand = strEmacsclientPath & " -c --eval " & Chr(34) _
    & "(org-search-view nil (decode-coding-string " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) _
    & strSearchText _
    & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & " locale-coding-system))" & Chr(34)
```